# How to determine time complexity of this code?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

I have just started learning algorithms,

```
int findMinPath(vector<vector<int> > &V, int r, int c){
    int R = V.size();
    int C = V[0].size();
    if (r >= R || c >= C) return 100000000; // Infinity
    if (r == R - 1 && c == C - 1) return 0;
    return V[r][c] + min(findMinPath(V, r + 1, c), findMinPath(V, r, c + 1));
}
```

I think the answer should be O(R*C) but the right answer is O(2^(R*C)) I cannot understand why. Please explain.

Comment: It's doubly recursive. If you map out the calls as a graph you get a binary call tree. The algorithm doesn't make sense to me though.

Comment: Hmm. Isn't it O((C+R) choose C), since the code is essentially enumerating paths from (0,0) to (C,R). ? That's O(2^(RC)) I think, but that's a pretty bad upper bound. For example, when R=C, (C+R) choose C is approximately 4^R/sqrt(pi*R), which grows much slower than 2^(R^2).

Comment: Perhaps there's a typo in the question: O(2^(R+C)) rather than O(2^(RC))? The depth of the search tree is at most R+C, so 2^(R+C) is a reasonable first approximation to the complexity. Of course R+C=O(RC), so the question as it stands is also theoretically correct, but doesn't make much practical sense (to me at least).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf the algorithm makes sense -- it finds the lowest cost path from (0,0) to (R,C) where all the steps are either right or up. It isn't the best way to write the code of course, but I assume this is the starting "bad" algorithm that will be improved by dynamic programming.

Comment: Oh, the `V[0].size()` threw me off. But apparently it's a matrix represented as a vector of vectors, not a general jagged array. So, Columns and Rows. Hm. All right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have multiple recursive calls, a good approximation is the number of branches (calls) raised to the power of the height of the "tree".

In your case, you have two branches:

```
findMinPath(V, r+1, c) 
findMinPath(V, r, c+1)
```

So we'll start with a base of 2.

Then the height (or depth) of your "tree" is determined by how many elements are in your vector; in your case, You have R elements, but each element has C elements in it. So our power is RC.

Thus your runtime will approximate, in the worst case to O(2^RC).

Comment: The maximum depth of the tree is R+C rather than RC isn't it? The initial distance from (R, C) is R+C, and the distance decreases by 1 each recursive call.

Comment: @PaulHankin I think it is because in worst case R*C all elements will be traversed so as Cruiser explained, It should be 2^(R*C)

Comment: In the worst case, in a single path, R+C (or perhaps R+C-2, but that makes no difference to the complexity) elements are traversed, not RC elements. There are RC elements in the vector, but the steps of your search paths in the grid go only in the directions (+1, 0) and (0, +1).

Answer (score 3):

Worst case scenario, `findMinPath` calls itself twice in this line

```
return V[r][c] + min(findMinPath(V, r + 1, c), findMinPath(V, r, c + 1));
```

So, worst case, every call will involve two further calls until this the recursion ends. Hence, two-to-the-power.

Comment: Why 2^(RC) and not, for example, 2^(R+C). Since R+C is the maximum depth of the search tree.